# The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contain too many digits

Tags: c#, timespan

Following code gives me error as shown in title above:

```
TimeSpan my_hours = new TimeSpan();
my_hours = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00");
my_hours += TimeSpan.Parse("25:07"); //this line throws error
```

Just before the last line runs value of my_hours is 4.01:33:00. How do I fix this error?

Basically this code is running in a for loop and the value "25:07" keeps changing and it adds in my_hours and it keeps doing it until it tries to add this value "25:07" when current value of my_hours is 4.01:33:00 and throws error.

Comment: I think `TimeSpan.Parse` method thinks your string like `hh:mm` format. Since there is no hour 25, so..

Comment: Hmm...that's what I also thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the third line to `my_hours += TimeSpan.Parse("00:25:07")`

You can read about the expected format of `TimeSpan.Parse()` [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The s parameter contains a time interval specification in the form:
>
> `[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]`

So the bare minimum that is required is `hh:mm`. When you put in `25:07`, it was interpreted as 25 hours, seven minutes, which is an illegal value (since hours need to be between 0-23).

Adding in `00:` in front changes it to 0 hours, 25 minutes and 7 seconds, which is now a legal value to parse.

Comment: Nice one and in my case is was trying to parse 00:60:00 as in 60 minutes but i should be using 01:00:00 for one hour. so basically be careful not to put numbers which are more than your units of time.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use more than 24 hours, you have to use a different format. The format that [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts is documented

```
[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]
```

So you have to specify `1.01:07` for 1 day, 1 hour and 7 minutes.

Comment: +1. Yeah, is it not funny how people do not even bother checking the documentation?

Comment: Stackoverflow is the documentation ;)

Comment: @TomTom - Apparently there's a lot of people out there that think StackOverflow is their own personal research assistant.

Answer (score 1):

According to [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation, format of expected string is

> [ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]

Where hh is hours, ranging from 0 to 23. So, string `25:07` is considered as `hh:mm` string with hours having value 25. That gives you OverflowException.

If you want to add 25 hours, then you should add 1 day and one hour `1:01:07`. If that supposed to be 25 minutes, then use format with seconds `00:25:07`